# How to represent classes called via JNI on a UML class diagram

Tags: java, android, class, opencv, diagram

Currently I am finishing up my Android project which detects numbers in real time using OpenCV and Tesseract. I have created a class diagram which consists of all the Java classes, but the problem is I do not know how to add into it, a class written in C++ (which is called via JNI). I think it would be important to show calls to this C++ class that happen from the Java side, but I have no idea what the associations should look like, as I have never seen a class diagram that consisted of anything other than Java classes.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What tool do you use for the class diagram?

Comment: ObjectAid UML Diagram on Eclipse. Mac OSX

Comment: UML is language-agnostic.  Why would it matter what the class was written it?  The question implies a misunderstanding of objects and UML.

Comment: Ok, never worked with that. Anyway, UML doesn't care about the programming language, so you can just add classes of different languages in the same diagram. In enterprise architect, you can still specify the programming language, but that doesn't have any visual effect. If you really want to stress the language, you could use a stereotype, or just add a note.

Comment: thanks for the help. Now I know how to do it i think. Thanks to Heuster. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define it as an interface with a stereotype, like <<native>>

see [UML stereotypes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cstereotyp.html) for a brief description of stereotypes.